# Redactor editor - How to set cursor at the end on focus

Tags: jquery, setfocus, redactor, redactor.js

I'm working on a project that uses redactor as an editor.
So every time I set focus using jQuery it's cursor goes on start.
I see an option focusEnd on it's documentations but it does not work maybe because I'm using rtl direction.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to set cursor at the end:

this.focus.setEnd();