# Imperavi Redactor - Caret always on the start

Tags: plugins, mustache, caret, redactor

my question is kinda similar to one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982416/redactor-editor-how-to-set-cursor-at-the-end-on-focus)

So, I have made several Redactor plugins, which generate html content from specific APIs (for example: Plugin that gets comments from API). Plugin than inserts HTML data into Redactor. However when HTML is inserted, caret (cursor) dissapears. That not something that I want, because if I want to add another plugin data, I' ll get this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'setStartAfter' on 'Range': the given Node has no parent.
```

the only way that I can avoid this problem is by clicking underneath inserted data. How can I fix this?

P.S. I use Mustache, for simplified html insertion.